# PyQt5 QObject+QGraphicsItem multi-inheritance causes crash on QGraphicsItem.setFlags()

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem, qobject

I discovered that, in a class inheriting from `QGraphicsItem` *and* `QObject`, calling `QGraphicsItem.setFlags()` causes immediate, errorless crash in PyQt5. The following example demonstrates this

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QMainWindow, QApplication


class Item(QObject, QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        QGraphicsItem.__init__(self)
        
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable |
                      QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges)

    def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
        return QRectF(0,0,50,50)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=...) -> None:
        painter.fillRect(self.boundingRect(), QColor('#555555'))


class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(400, 300)
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        scene.setSceneRect(0,0,self.width(),self.height())
        self.setScene(scene)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event) -> None:
        QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        if event.isAccepted():
            return

        newitem = Item()
        self.scene().addItem(newitem)
        newitem.setPos(event.pos())


class ViewWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(View())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = ViewWindow()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The same code works fine with PySide2. Did I miss something there? I'm using Python 3.9.5 and PyQt5 5.15.4.

Comment: Generally, multiple inheritance of Qt objects doesn't correctly work in PyQt. And, in any case, why don't you use [QGraphicsObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html)? It's exactly what you're trying to achieve, since it both inherits from QObject and QGraphicsItem (but on the Qt side).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know this was a no-go. I can't remember why I didn't use `QGraphicsObject`, if there wasn't a reason then I should probably use it, yeah. Though, I also just discovered further crucial issues with dinamically built classes and PyQt5 (even without multi-inheritance) so I might drop PyQt5 support completely :/

Comment: single inheritance never creates a problem, so you probably did something wrong somewhere: I have built Qt subclasses dynamically in the past, it's not always easy, but everytime I had an issue I discovered that the problem was on my side. I suggest you to find a good case for your issue and post a question about it.